Help me prove a specific integration formula
How does one prove that Integrate[x^(2n)/Sqrt[1-x^2],{x,-1,1}] where n is a positive integer is equal to Pi*(2n)!/(4^n*n!^2) which I found from the general formula which uses Gamma function. I have tried by part integration to find some recurrence relation but that did not work. Any suggestions? This formula is needed to use Gram-Schmidt to derive Chebyshev polynomials.
